# AWS Java SDK - Elastic Transcoder set Start time and Duration on InputJob

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I'm using the Java SDK to create a Elastic Transcoding Job.

In the documentation, I can set Job settings https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/job-settings.html#job-settings-input-details which includes start time and duration.

I'm using com.amazonaws.services.elastictranscoder.model.JobInput

to create the input, there are no options for Start or Duration.

Is it possible to add these somewhere?

Answer (score -1):

SDK out of date and there is a new TimeSpan attribute in the latest version.